# Visio 2013 Text box within a connector

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2013

visio 2013 how do I move the text box within a connector?  Works in 2010 where I just click the box until it turns yellow and then i can drag it to where I want it on the connector line but in 2013 this is not working.. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Select the connector, then use the **Text Block** tool from the ribbon (**Alt-Shift-4**). This will work with all shapes (including all connectors) in all cases.

Comment: To clarify Paul's answer, the **Text Block** tool is (**Shift-Control-4**) in Visio 2013.